# Q: How to find the mean, variance, and marginal density of a random variable that is defined conditionally in terms of another random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If given the following question

“Let $X_1$ be uniform[0,1] and define  $X_2$|$X_1$=$x_1$ to be Uniform [0,$x_1$]

Find the mean variance and marginal density of $X_2$ and verify that the density found is indeed a density”

I think I’m supposed to proceed by using the tower property or law of iterate expectations.

That is take E[E[$X_2$|$X_1$]]=E[$X_2$]

But I’m not exactly sure how to carry this out...

My sense is that this will help me to construct an integral which I can manipulate to find the mean variance, and marginal density.

Comment: I'd  represent $X_2$ as the product of 2 independent uniforms, and express all moments as integrals over the unit square.

Comment: See here for computing the marginal density: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7631/problem-calculating-joint-and-marginal-distribution-of-two-uniform-distributions From there computing the marginal mean and variance is straightforward.